# In trying to repair grub, I get an "Uncompression Error System Halted" notice

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, grub2, windows-8, boot-repair

I had Ubuntu 12 .04 then installed windows. As usual, it wiped out my Ubuntu 12.04 grub. So I tried using a live CD to repair grub. However, the CD never really load and after eternity it gives me an "Uncompression Error System Halted" notice.

Note: My 12.04 was an upgrade from 11.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot-Repair is a great easy to use tool that also has a live disc so you can boot from it and repair boot related issues, it can be found at the link below.

[Boot-Repair Live Disc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)

**Resources**

[Boot-Repair - Ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Using%20Boot-Repair)

Comment: I will get back to you when I try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like charm.

Comment: Great I'm glad it worked for you.